# Configure an interface to respond to all IP addresses, even external ones?

Tags: ip, utilities

**Edit 2: Found a tool upon closer inspection of documentations.**

Situation: Loving the [`FakeDNS`](https://github.com/Crypt0s/FakeDns) tool to get a machine to reply with its own IP address to all DNS requests made by a malware sample.

But when the malware sample reaches out to an IP address, it will be dropped if the target machine does not happen to be the same IP.

Question: Is there a tool similar to `FakeDNS`, but instead it replied to any IP addresses that is queried? In my mind I am thinking of a script that will configure a network interface in response to an ARP request.

Preferably tool should run on Linux

**Edit 1:**

Hopefully the setup should be similar to what I usually do for malware analysis - just 2 VMs in a closed network (no internet).

```
10.1.1.1        10.1.1.2
-------         -------
| VM1 |=========| VM2 |
-------         -------
```

Where VM1 will execute the malware, while VM2 runs all the other networking stuff, including `FakeDNS`. I have full control over both VMs and the host.

E.g.1 `FakeDNS`, just an example how it works:

- VM1 is configured to have VM2 as default gateway and DNS server.
- VM2 has `FakeDNS` running.
- Run malware `a.exe` on VM1.
- Malware on VM1 asks for `example.org` from DNS server.
- VM2 replies with own IP address (`example.org -> 10.1.1.2`).

E.g.2 `"Script/tool/config X"`:

- VM1 is configured to have VM2 as default gateway.
- VM2 has `script/tool/config X`.
- Run malware `b.exe` on VM1.
- Malware on VM1 asks for `8.8.8.8` (`"Who has 8.8.8.8?"`).
- VM2 replies with `"I am 8.8.8.8"` regardless of configured IP address

Comment: Good catch. I've updated my question -- I just need a (virtual) machine to reply to any IP address request, just like how `fakedns` will reply to any DNS request

Comment: "Is there a tool that does X?" are off-topic here. And what you want is a Linux command that configures an interface to respond to all or a configurable range of IPs. This is more of a Linux networking question, not a security question, even though you want to use it for security purposes.

Comment: Alright understood. thank you for your time anyway

Comment: It's a routing configuration. So the tool is `ip route` , `ip rule` & co. But I'd rather have OP give an example network to avoid having to guess too much configuration. Actually a complete example would be needed in the question to avoid confusion and a lot of comments

Comment: Question updated

Comment: DNSChef can do this - https://github.com/iphelix/dnschef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have failed to mention that VM2 is REMnux, and I was having a closer look at [REMnux's cheatsheet](https://zeltser.com/media/docs/remnux-malware-analysis-tips.pdf) and its tools looking for a different tool, and I realised that it includes a script to [`accept-all-ips`](https://github.com/REMnux/distro/blob/master/files/accept-all-ips).

The script uses IPtables' NAT table to redirect traffic back to itself, thereby able to reply to any IP address.